# loaded a subversion dump but it's inaccessible

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I received a dump file of a SVN repository that I'm moving to my server.  Let's call it myserver.com/svn.  The load statement prints out a long list of files loaded and reports no error.  However, once I try to access the repository for checkout, or relocate my existing checkout, I'm told:

```
Repository moved temporarily to 'http://www.myserver.com/svn'; please relocate
```

In other words, my new repository reports that it has temporarily moved to itself.  How do I get past that?  I can't find anything about this message in documentation about the svnadmin load command.

Comment: Not verified. Just a lead:

http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=7226
"To exclude a site from being passed through the proxy it must be configured in the Subversion "servers" file instead under the "http-proxy-exceptions" option."

Answer (score 1):

subversion generates a UUID (Universally Unique ID) whenever it creates a repository.  I believe that in order to use the UUID from your original repo you need to ad "--force-uuid" to your svnadmin load command.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html

Answer (score 0):

I think someone has added a hook script to inform you that your repository is now at another URL.

If this was not expected, it might indicate a security issue.

Comment: No, that's not it.  This error message resulted immediately after the load.  And anyway it's informing me that my repository is now at the SAME url.

Comment: Are you using Apache?  If so, can you see the repo in a browser?  If not, then I'd check the apache config.  

Can you create a new repository OK on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

I heard of a few cases where this was caused by adding a '/' at the end of the path in the <Location directive in the apache configuration.

Please remove the '/' if you added one.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your server is configured to redirect all errors to somewhere (ie the homepage). The line you should look for would be called something like

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.myserver.com/svn
```

SVN apparently uses 404 (not found) errors in order to add new resources. You must allow this one to pass through instead of making a redirection, or svn will get confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  by any chance and have an .htaccess file somewhere around the DocumentRoot directory of the VirtualHost, try removing it and see if it helps. :)